# Segfault with making a word lowercase function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a function that tries to make all the letters in a word lowercase, if needed. I debugged my program and found out I was getting my segfault from this function. Both word and lowerword are strings.

Here is the call:

```
lowerword = word_to_lower(word);
```

Here is the function itself:

```
char * word_to_lower(char * word) {
  int i;
  char * lowerword;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); ++i) {
    lowerword = (char *) tolower(word[i]);
    printf("%s\n", lowerword);
  }

  return lowerword;
}
```

I am very new to C so a detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `lowerword = (char *) tolower(word[i]);` This is a classic case of casting to silence the compiler (and gone wrong)  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast a `char` in `char*` which are two different things. The first is a value (a character), the second is a pointer (a variable which points to a location in the memory at which there is a character stored). If you want to return a completely processed string, you should first allocate an array of char of the size `strlen(word)`, and then setting its elements (i.e. each character) to the proper value with the call to `toLower`.

In the end, you should have something like

```
char * word_to_lower(const char * word) {
  int i;
  unsigned int length = strlen(word);
  char * lowerword = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    lowerword[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    printf("%c\n", lowerword[i]);
  }

  return lowerword;
}
```

Be sure you understand the concepts behind "pointers" and "arrays" in C, and the processes of allocating and freeing memory. It seems by the way you use them that you're not comfortable with these.

EDIT : As remarked in the comments, this function should take a `const char *` as a parameter.

Comment: @Jonfor Beware that 1. this method modifies its argument, 2. as such it will also error out when you pass it constant strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
lowerword = (char *) tolower(word[i]);
printf("%s\n", lowerword)
```

Nah. `tolower()` returns an `int` (that you can assign to a `char`).

```
char lowerword;
lowerword = tolower(word[i]);
printf("%c\n", lowerword)
```

Comment: But I am casting to char *. Why does that not work?

Comment: @Jonfor: You're changing the address to which `lowerword` points to whatever `tolower` returns.

Comment: @Jonfor because casting ain't no magic. If `printf()` encounters `%s`, it expects a `char *` - a pointer from where it can fetch characters one after another. But you give it the numeric value of a char, and when it tries to interpret it as an address, BOOM!

Comment: OH it can't just cast like that! I understand now, thank you :)

Comment: @Jonfor Yap, casting is just for fooling the compiler. Remember that C is a weakly-typed and not very high-level languages. If you pass it a `char`, the exact value of the `char` will be passed down, whatever you do with it. Pure, raw, numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lower the case of the whole string :

```
void word_to_lower(char * word) {
  int i, len = strlen(word);
  for (i = 0; i < len ; ++i) {
      word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
  }
}
```